# Check all loaded modules if it comes from the OS or if it's automatically loaded at run time

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-code

**I've conducted the following experiment:**

I noticed that when I start the program/exe it will automatically load modules/dll. Here is the list of modules loaded automatically:

```
D:\test.exe

C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL

C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll

C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll

C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9279_none_50939ec6bcb7c97c\MSVCP90.dll

C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9279_none_50939ec6bcb7c97c\MSVCR90.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL

C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\SspiCli.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll

C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll

C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll
```

**My objectives:**

I wanted to check whether the DLL/module is loaded by the operating system automatically or loaded by using LoadLibrary API.

If this is a duplicate question. Can you please guide me to the solution?

Thank you and Good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 possible approaches:

- First alternative, run the application in DependencyWalker.  This utility can tell you when a DLL is loaded.  This might give you some hints.
- Second alternative, start the application in a debugger and put a breakpoint in main.  Then investigate the loaded modules in Visual Studio.  These modules were automatically loaded by Windows.  When the breakpoint is hit, but a breakpoint on the Windows function LoadLibrary (and LoadLibraryEx) and see when it's hit.  These modules are manually loaded (and you can immediately see who loads them).

The second approach assumes that there is not a DLL that explicitly calls LoadLibrary itself in its DllMain method.  However, doing that would be bad practice since it could lead to a deadlock on the Loader Lock.

Comment: A breakpoint in `main` fires _after_ initializers of global objects (such as constructors). You'd need a breakpoint on the CRT entry point.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I will try the DependencyWalker first. Dependency walker can tell like this?
**Windows 7 32 bit**
dll1 name
dll2 name
**Windows 7 64 bit**
dll1 name
dll2 name
dll3 name

and so on...

Comment: How about this. Can I verify that the module/dll is a windows dll?

Comment: @MSalters.  You're right.  It's better to put a breakpoint earlier.

Comment: @LearningCPP.  You can programmatically get the full path of a module and see where it's loaded from.  So if it's loaded from C:\Windows then it's probably a Windows DLL, but Windows DLL's could also be loaded from the side-by-side cache (WinSxS).  You can check all loaded DLL's using utilities like Process Explorer and see where they are loaded from.  Dependency Walker also reports the DLL's used by an executable, but my experience is that it doesn't correctly use the manifest, so often refers to DLL's from a location that is not used (or refers to 32-bit DLL's from a 64-bit executable).

Comment: @Patrick Thank you sir, I will experiment with the breakpoint in main. I tried dependency walker but it is not accurate. Sir what if I will put a dll inside C:\Windows\System32\fool.dll. fool.dll can fool the validation whether it is a windows dll or not.

Comment: @LearningCPP: if allow users to put non-Windows DLL's in C:\Windows or C:\Windows\System32, you possibly have a security problem.